# Filter() in Angular2

Tags: angular, filter, filtering

I have

```
Product: {code: string, description: string}
productsA: Product[]
productsB: Product[]
```

I want to get productsC: Product[] that contains all products of productsA that have 'code' other than productsB's product codes

Example:

```
  productsA = [{'c1', 'des1'}, {'c2', 'des2'}, {'c3', 'des3'}]
  productsB = [{'c1', 'des4'}]
  I want productsC = [{'c2', 'des2'}, {'c3', 'des3'}]
```

How can I do?

Comment: there is no key for product code?

Comment: 'code' is the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need all products from `productsA`, except that `productsB` includes?

Here you go then.

```js
const productA = [{code: 'c1', description: 'desc1'}, {code: 'c2', description: 'desc2'}, {code: 'c3', description: 'desc3'}];
const productB = [{code: 'c1', description: 'desc1'}];
const productC = [];

productA.forEach(prodA => {
  productB.forEach(prodB => {
    if (prodA.code != prodB.code) {
      productC.push(prodA);
    }    
  });
});

console.log(productC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `differenceBy` of `lodash`.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash-es';

yourFunc() {
      :
    const productsC = _.differenceBy(productsA, productsB, 'code');
      :
}
```